# How to correctly type no-arg and withVar constructors in a generic class?

Tags: java, generics

I'm working on a (Java 8+) class that I want to be built using a sort of "builder" pattern where you chain a no-argument constructor to one or more setters that return the same object. Basically here's my class:

```
public class MyClass {
  private int foo;
  private String bar;

  public MyClass() {
    System.out.println("initializing instance of MyClass");
  }
  public MyClass withFoo(int foo) {
    this.foo=foo;
    return this;
  }
  public MyClass withBar(String bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
    return this;
  }
}
```

The typical way you'd initialize it is

```
MyClass anInstance = new Myclass().withFoo(42).withBar("helloworld");
```

It's a nice pattern, but I've never used it with a generic class before.  Now I want to generify my class.  I've made changes to the class signature and the constructor, withFoo, and withBar methods:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
  private int foo;
  private String bar;

  public MyClass() {
    System.out.println("initializing instance of MyClass");
  }
  public MyClass<T> withFoo(int foo) {
    this.foo=foo;
    return this;
  }
  public MyClass<T> withBar(String bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
    return this;
  }
}
```

Note that `foo` and `bar` themselves aren't going to change type.  Nothing of type `<T>` is going to be passed in via a `withVar()` method.

I have some clues that this isn't the best way to do it.  The standard no-argument constructor seems to work fine:

- **works fine:** `MyClass<Float> myInstance = new MyClass<>();`

But if I add a `withVar` function I get an error at compile time (java: incompatible types: MyClass cannot be converted to MyClass).

- **won't compile:** `MyClass<Float> myInstance = new MyClass<>().withFoo(42);`

I can make it work by specifying the type twice, like so:

- **works fine:** `MyClass<Float> myInstance = new MyClass<Float>().withFoo(42);`

Is there a better way to code this, so that the generic type is carried over correctly to the right side of the assignment operator?

Comment: No better way, if you don't provide a constructor parameter of appropriate type. (e.g. `new MyClass<>(0.f)`). It annoys me it doesn't work with Guava's ImmutableList builders: e.g. `ImmutableList.<String>builder().add("").build()`.

Comment: A generic static factory method might be able to guess the correct generic type.

Comment: Why do you want to make `MyClass` generic if you don't then use `T`?

Comment: @khelwood ^^ no, see my comment about `ImmutableList.builder()`. Unless you mean a factory method for specifically returning a `MyClass<Float>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I do use `T` for the data the class processes, but `foo` and `bar` in this case are configurations that tell the class how to behave, and they don't change type.

Comment: @AndyTurner I understand now, the generic-guessing doesn't work when you're chaining methods in the same statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two ways I can to do this are to add a constructor parameter which specifies the type:

```
MyClass<Float> instance = new MyClass<>(0.f).withFoo(42).withBar("helloworld");
```

or by adding a "terminal cast" method:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
  // ...

  public MyClass() { ... }

  public <U> MyClass<U> cast() {
    MyClass<U> copy = new MyClass<>();
    return copy.withFoo(foo).withBar(bar);
  }

  public MyClass<T> withFoo(int foo) { ... }
  public MyClass<T> withBar(String bar) { ... }
}
```

which you can then invoke like:

```
MyClass<Float> instance = new MyClass<>().withFoo(42).withBar("helloworld").cast();
```

---

A third way would be to provide a factory method for creating `MyClass<Float>` instances specifically:

```
static MyClass<Float> newFloatInstance() { return new MyClass<>(); }
```

which you can then invoke like:

```
MyClass<Float> instance = newFloatInstance().withFoo(42).withBar("helloworld");
```

but I guess you might not really want to have to have factory methods for each possible type.

---

But note that if you're able to do this without supplying something to the cast method (or the constructor) which ties the instance of `MyClass` to its type argument, you don't *really* need a type variable on the class.

You could just push the type variable onto just the method which requires that type variable:

```
public class MyClass {
  // ...

  public <T> T doSomethingToSpecificType(List<T> list, T arg) {
    // do something type-specific.
  }
}
```